# Adding import table rate csv function for custom shipping module

Tags: php

i make new custom shipping module for magento shipping, just wondering actually how to make import csv function in main website, Thanks

```
                <import translate="label">
                    <label>Import</label>
                    <frontend_type>import</frontend_type>
                    <backend_model>jne_adminhtml/system_config_backend_shipping_mycarrier</backend_model>
                    <sort_order>40</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                </import>

class MyCustomization_MyCarrier_Model_Adminhtml_System_Config_Backend_Shipping_MyCarrier extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{
    public function _afterSave()
    {
        Mage::getResourceModel('mycarrier_shipping/carrier_mycarrier')->uploadAndImport($this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You also have to create the resource model and of course the database table. You can view/copy the files for Tablerate shipping method and to replace tablerate with your carrier code - `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Resource/Carrier/Tablerate.php` (resource model) and `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/sql/shipping_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php` (db table).